# Hashing a variable in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, variables, hash, passwords, md5

I'm using python 3 and i need to know how to use hashing in python 3 on a variable instead of a string.

my example;
this is the code i'm currently trying to use and it doesn't work.

```
foundpassencypt = hashlib.md5(b(pwd))
print(foundpassencypt.hexdigest())
```

pwd is a string that was entered earlier in my program.

```
pwd = "Password"
```

i know if it was a string it would be layed out like this;

```
foundpassencypt = hashlib.md5(b"Password")
print(foundpassencypt.hexdigest())
```

This is the full code (its using Python3, SQL Lite and [Appjar](http://appjar.info/))("Else:" is out of place when i post the code, its correct in my code)

```
    else:
    usr = login.getEntry("Username")
    pwd = login.getEntry("Password") #collects entry of password & username

    conn = sqlite3.connect("uHubDatabase.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor() #connects to database

    find_user=("SELECT Username FROM UserTable WHERE Username = ?") #sets the finding of the username from the database as a varaible 
    cursor.execute(find_user,[(usr)])


    founduser = str(cursor.fetchall())
    print(founduser)
    removechars = "'(),[]" #Avoids the error of special characters caused by the database outputting strings (Text)
    for char in removechars:
        founduser = founduser.replace(char,'')

    find_pass=("SELECT Password FROM UserTable WHERE Password = ?") #sets the finding of the password from the database as a varaible 
    cursor.execute(find_pass,[(pwd)])

    foundpass = str(cursor.fetchall())
    print(foundpass)
    removechars = "'(),[]" #Avoids the error of special characters caused by the database outputting strings (Text)
    for char in removechars:
        foundpass = foundpass.replace(char,'')

    pwdencypt = hashlib.md5(pwd) #makes the encypted password using md5 hashing
    print(pwdencypt.hexdigest()) # checks the string for comparison

    print(founduser) 
    print(usr) 
    print(foundpass) 
    print(pwd) 

    if founduser == usr and foundpass == pwdencypt: # If correct
        print("SUCESS")
        login.stop()
        home.go()

    else: #if incorrect
        print("FAIL")
        login.retryBox("INCORRECT LOGIN", "The Username or Password entered are incorrect. Please try again.", parent=login)
    print("User:", usr, "Pass:", pwd)

    conn.close() #closes connection
```

Comment: DO NOT USE MD5 TO HASH PASSWORDS.  Do not use only a single round of any hash to hash passwords.  Do use BCrypt, SCrypt, PBKDF2, or Argon2 with a sufficiently high iteration count/work factor to hash passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before hashing a string variable you should encode it first.

Example:

```
a = "123321"
print(hashlib.md5(a.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
```

Comment: this gives me an error `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'hexdigest'`

Answer (score 1):

**DO NOT USE MD5 FOR HASHING PASSWORDS**

It is extremely insecure for a wide number of reasons, not the least of which being that a single iteration of any hash is insufficient, and another of which is that MD5 collisions can now be generated (and have been able to be generated for years).

Use PBKDF2, BCrypt, SCrypt, or Argon2 with a high iteration count/work factor to hash passwords.

Note that I do have a crude but functional Python 2.7 example of PBKDF2 in [my Github repository](https://github.com/Anti-weakpasswords/PBKDF2-Python-hmaclib-custom-A).  An example of a call is:

```
BinaryOutput = pbkdf2_math.pbkdf2_bin(args.password, args.salt, args.iterations, args.outputBytes, hashlib.sha512)
```

Alternately, use [passlib for Python 2 and 3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/passlib) to call PBKDF2, BCrypt, SCrypt, or Argon2.

In ALL cases, use a sufficiently high iteration count or work factor; start with, perhaps, whatever takes 1/10th or 1/100th of one second to hash a single password (and that'll be using only one core on your system, so multi-core system can do multiple passwords at once).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `b()`

```
import hashlib
pwd = "Password"
foundpassencypt = hashlib.md5(pwd.encode('utf-8'))
print(foundpassencypt.hexdigest())
```

Output:

```
dc647eb65e6711e155375218212b3964
```

UPD. Hashing algortithm doesn't support unicode so you have to encode your sring. See python [issue2948](https://bugs.python.org/issue2948) for details

Comment: TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Comment: Then you need to encode it as the hashing algorithm doesn't support unicode. You still won't need `b`

Comment: How do i "encode it as the hashing algorithm doesn't support unicode."?

Comment: I've included it into the code above, `pwd.encode('utf-8')` part

Comment: the other answer has that as well

Comment: Thanks, will try now

Comment: the code is now saying that the foundpass and pwdencypt dont match and is going to output fail. Mo errors though, so i think the code works. odd though

Comment: This is the part its doing saying they don't match                                                   
                                                                                                             
        else: #if incorrect
        print("FAIL")
        login.retryBox("INCORRECT LOGIN", "The Username or Password entered are incorrect. Please try again.", parent=login)
    print("User:", usr, "Pass:", pwd)

Comment: [('Sam200029',)]
[]
479b1e1b74e2d3a2bf8963a7953b268d
Sam200029
Sam200029

Buster123
FAIL
User: Sam200029 Pass: Buster123

Comment: it seems like now is the time to debug your app logic

Comment: Thats the output, looks like its no longer collecting the password??